# Do the eigenvalues of $|\sqrt\rho\sqrt\sigma|$ have a physical interpretation?

Tags: fidelity

The (square-root) [fidelity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states) between a pair of states $\rho,\sigma$ is the quantity
$$\sqrt F(\rho,\sigma) = \|\sqrt\rho\sqrt\sigma\|_1 = \operatorname{tr}|\sqrt\rho\sqrt\sigma|
=\operatorname{tr}\left[\sqrt{\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho}\right].$$
Here $|\sqrt\rho\sqrt\sigma|\equiv \sqrt{\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, and thus $\sqrt F$ equals the sum of its eigenvalues.

Can the individual eigenvalues of $|\sqrt\rho\sqrt\sigma|$ be given any kind of physical (or otherwise) interpretation? This should also be equivalent to asking about the eigenvalues of $\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho$, which in turn are equal to the eigenvalues of $\rho\sigma$ (which as discussed [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9938/55) is ensured to be diagonalisable).