# Explanation of the 2.60 equation page 76 in the Nielsen and Chuang

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, linear-algebra

In the Nielsen and Chuang book page 76, equation 2.60 says that we can rewrite the trace $$Tr(A \left|\psi\right>\left<\psi\right|)$$ as follow :

$$Tr(A \left|\psi\right>\left<\psi\right|) = \sum_{i}^{}\langle i| A | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | i \rangle 
= \langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle$$

I understand the idea behind, but I don't manage to do the calculus with the gram-schmidt procedure can lead to such a result.

On addition, I don't understant how $$\sum_{i}^{}\langle i| A | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | i \rangle 
= \langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle$$

Answer (score 0):

> In the Nielsen and Chuang book page 76, equation 2.60 says that we can rewrite the trace $$Tr(A \left|\psi\right>\left<\psi\right|)$$ as follow :
>
> $$Tr(A \left|\psi\right>\left<\psi\right|) = \sum_{i}^{}\langle i| A | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | i \rangle 
> = \langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle$$

> On addition, I don't understant how $$\sum_{i}^{}\langle i| A | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | i \rangle 
> = \langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle$$

The $|i\rangle$ are assumed to be a complete set. Use the completeness relation:
$$
1 = \sum_{i}|i\rangle\langle i|
$$

Thus:
$$\sum_{i}^{}\langle i| A | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | i \rangle 
=\sum_{i}^{}\langle \psi| i \rangle\langle i| A | \psi \rangle  
$$
$$
=\langle \psi| \sum_{i}^{}| i \rangle\langle i|A | \psi \rangle 
=\langle \psi| 1\times A | \psi \rangle
= \langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation of this part, but now how can we proove $$Tr(A|ψ⟩⟨ψ|)=∑i⟨i|A|ψ⟩⟨ψ|i⟩$$ ?

Comment: This follows from the *definition* of the trace as the sum of diagonal elements: $Tr(M) = \sum_i M_{ii}$.

Comment: It is basic linear algebra that the trace is the sum of diagonal elements in any orthonormal complete basis and the trace is independent of the basis chosen.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by @hft, see the discussion at [Can we combine the square roots inside the definition of the fidelity?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/can-we-combine-the-square-roots-inside-the-definition-of-the-fidelity)

In particular the invariance of trace when you do cyclic rearrangement of the product terms.